# How do I include commands in an echo statement?

Tags: echo

Pretty simple, but I didn't find a question on here that asked this exactly.

I thought this would work but it does not.

```
echo "Your disk usage is ${df -k -h}."
```

How do I make the above work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$()`, not `${}`

```sh
echo "Your disk usage is $(df -h)."
```

Note that `df -h` has multi-line output (one line for the header, and one for each mounted filesystem), so including it in an echo statement looks quite ugly.

You can work around that by being more specific about what you want to display (e.g. only disk usage for the fs that contains your home dir) and extracting only the details you want to print.  For example:

```sh
printf 'Your disk usage on %s is %s\n' $(df -h ~ | awk 'NR==2 {print $6, $3}')
```

Comment: Thanks! Guess I had my brackets and parenthesis mixed up.

Comment: note that `df -k -h` has multi-line output (one line for header, and one for each mount), so including it in an `echo` statement won't look good.

Comment: Is there any way around this? If so can you include it in your answer?

Comment: There's no generic way around it, it depends on what exactly you want to show (e.g. just / or ~) and how many filesystems you have mounted (e.g. `df | wc -l` on my system is `34` largely because I use zfs and have lots of zfs filesystems on my zpools).     To just display `df` for the fs that contains your home dir, try : `echo "Your disk usage is $(df -h ~ | sed 1d)."`

Comment: btw, it doesn't make any sense to use both `-k` and `-h` options of `df`.

Comment: another alternative is something like `printf 'Your disk usage on %s is %s\n' $(df -h ~| awk '/\// {print $6, $3}')`

Answer (score 0):

in `ksh` you need:

```
echo "... ${df -k -h;}"
```

If you want to show a percent of usage for the filesystem in which the current directory is rooted and if you are using a linux system with an up-to-date `util-linux` package installed, you should do:

```
printf "Your disk usage is:\t"
(until findmnt -noTARGET,USE% .;do cd ..; done)
```